# Android espresso No views in hierarchy found matching

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-espresso

I was trying to find a view and tried different combinations but my logic looks right according to all stackoverflow examples.

My code:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(
                   instanceOf(ListView::class.java))
                .atPosition(0)
                .onChildView(withId(android.R.id.title))
                .check(matches(withText("Edit")))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

And it throws error:

```
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: android:id/title and is descendant of a:  displaying data matching: ANYTHING within adapter view matching: an instance of android.widget.ListView)
    If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView{3df3337 VFED.VC.. ........ 0,0-539,264}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: What happens if you just simple use: `onView(withId(R.id.title)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); `

Comment: That works. I was curious if I can do onData () here or may be I should not overthink here and do it simple

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with this for your case. Unfortunately, I cannot be sure about how onData() could work here but after researching you should try something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.title))
    .check(matches(withText("Edit")))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```